# Android Text to Speech playback queue

Tags: android

Is it possible to access the playback queue used by the android TextToSpeech Engine? I want to know the index of the element of the playbackqueue which the tts engine is currently speaking

Answer (score 0):

**File rendering and playback** While the speakOut() method is used to make Android speak the text right away, there are cases where you would want the result of the synthesis to be recorded in an audio file instead. This would be the case if, for instance, there is text your application will speak often; you could avoid the synthesis CPU-overhead by rendering only once to a file, and then playing back that audio file whenever needed. Just like for speak(), you can use an optional utterance identifier to be notified on the completion of the synthesis to the file:

```
HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap();
String wakeUpText = "Are you up yet?";
String destFileName = "/sdcard/myAppCache/wakeUp.wav";
myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, wakeUpText);
mTts.synthesizeToFile(wakuUpText, myHashRender, destFileName);
```

Once you are notified of the synthesis completion, you can play the output file just like any other audio resource with `android.media.MediaPlayer`.